# How to read all folder's name in desktop?

Tags: c#

I want to get all folder's name in my desktop,

[image]

I want to put it in my list.
Any code for this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: If you want us to write code for you, without any effort from you, then we want your money.

Comment: Is googling harder than posting questions on SO ?

Comment: @Dennis I had sample code here I just want a clear question, to many elaborated question may cause of misleading. I work to learn not to earn money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))
            .GetDirectories().Select(d => d.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path ))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d); // add 'd' to list or whats on ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

foreach (var file in d.GetFiles())
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```

To get directories only

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetDirectories(filepath))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```

or you can also do to get access to common Desktop folder

```
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(filepath, filter);
```

`filepath` is the location where your directories are listed, in this case, it's your desktop, so pass your desktop location. `filter` is e.g. if you only want to get the directories that start with a particular alphabet etc.